# Notice (8): Undefined index

Tags: php, cakephp, undefined-index

I'm trying to make a cakephp project work on my local computer, after setting up everything the login page works perfectly, after login in I'm getting this error:
[image]

and this is the code of line 111:
[image]

some help please!

My friends have the same code and it's working for them

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, I think the problem is in my php.ini but I don't know what is it

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($usu)`

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir the output is null

Comment: then seems like the user doesn't have a session saved

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir but my friends have the same thing and it's working for them

Comment: your query is not send the value to you, please check the what value you get from model and go for next

Comment: output cannot be null because you are checking for this in line 109. so again, try to var_dump($usu) after line 108

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir yes I did it after the line 108 and it's a null

Comment: then your if statement on line 109 would not be true and you wouldn't get the exception you got. The fact that you got it shows $usu AKA user session was not null and in fact did have a UID key

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir yes I'm supposed to get a uid but I don't and I couldn't figure out why?! what makes me more confused is that the project as it is, is working for my friends while it doesn't for me!!

Comment: do you have an authenticated user?

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir yes I have

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir could the problem be in my configuration?

Comment: @Lara I am sorry, not saying you are wrong, but the example presented above shows the value of $usu is not null. try again to var_dump after having a correct session. Also what you are doing in line 111 is redundant, you can simply remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217908/discussion-between-lara-and-mehrdad-dastgir).

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir I've done the var_dump and I'm getting array(0) { }